# Where can you find the less compiler installed in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, less, webstorm

I'm working on a NodeJS project in webstorm. I installed the Less compiler using "npm install less". I cannot find the lessc.cmd file in the NodeJS directory which Webstorm is supposed to use for compilation. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lessc` should be located in `node_modules/.bin/lessc` in your projects root directory.

Comment: Thank you! Here's another problem I'm not able to solve. I appreciate your help.